# Add text to matplotlib figure after mouseclick

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter

The code below creates a pandas dataframe and then plots the data in a scatter. For purposes that make sense in the larger app, I need it to post to a tkinter frame, so I've simulated all that in the MRE. Where I'm hung up is I want a text box to pop up when the user clicks on one of the data points. In the code below, the `mpl_connect` does call the `show_text` function because the `print(idx)` works. However my line creating a `ax.text` doesn't seem to be doing anything.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from tkinter import *

class TestClass(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=['A','B'])
        self.show_chart()

    def show_chart(self):
        g_top = Toplevel(bg='white')
        g_top.title('Spread/Leverage chart')
        x = self.parent.winfo_x()
        y = self.parent.winfo_y()
        w = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.4
        h = self.parent.winfo_screenheight() * 0.6
        g_top.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

        can = Canvas(g_top, bg='white')
        can.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

        frm = Frame(can, bg='white')
        can.create_window((4,4), window=frm, anchor='nw')

        fig = Figure(figsize=(6,6), dpi=100)
        fig.set_facecolor('white')
        ax = fig.gca()
        chart_type = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, frm)
        chart_type.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.df.plot(kind='scatter', ax=ax, x='A', y='B',
                    picker=True)

        #Create annotation
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', lambda event, ax=ax: self.show_text(event, ax))

    def show_text(self, event, ax):
        #Add text to chart
        idx = event.ind
        print(idx)
        ax.text(0.05, 0.95, 'Ind' + str(idx), transform=ax.transAxes, verticalalignment='top')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root=Tk()
    ui = TestClass(root)
    ui.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you forget to redraw the canvas after making changes to it? (`fig.canvas.draw()`)

Comment: OMG. That's embarrassing. That did it.